# How to pass cucumber tags for a TestRunner run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, tags, cucumber, testng

I need to pass specific `@example` cucumber tag with my TestRunner class execution.

I know that I can configure which tags I want to include in the run in the CucumberOptions of the TestRunner class. I'm not doing that, because I want to have several Runs configured with specific tags, so that I don't need to edit TestRunner class each time I change what is run.

This is part of my TestRunner class:

[image: part of my TestRunner class]

As you can see, I have removed the `, tags = "@example"` part and instead included `-Dcucumber.options="--tags @example"` in the VM options of the Run Configuration dialog:

[image: Run Configuration dialog]

But that doesn't work. When I run this, everything gets executed as if there was no tag information at all. What do I need to change, so that I can pass tags in the Run Configuration dialog?

Comment: I deleted my answer because now I am not sure. It has been a while. I need more time to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured it out. Instead of

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @example"
```

use

```
-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@example
```

in the VM options of the run.

You can leave `@tags` in the `CucumberOptions` in the TestRunner (no need to remove the line or comment it out), it will be overriden by the tags passed through VM options of the run.